# Form returned by drupal_get_form() won't submit

Tags: forms, users

I am currently implementing an additional registration page on my drupal site, using drupal_get_form(), but I seem to be missing something cucial.

While the registration form is printed at the path I created, I can not submit the form - drupal will clear both the user and the email field and return an error claiming the form could not be submitted, because the fields were empty. They were not.

Do I need to hook up a custom validation handler? Something else?

My code so far:

```
function my_module_menu() {
  $items['customer/register'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('my_module_customer_registration'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

 return $items;
}

function my_module_customer_registration() {
  $form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the problem or not but it looks like you have superfluous code. You should be able to call the form directly from your hook_menu. `'page arguments' => array('user_registration_form')`. Could be an issue with your form name and submit handlers calling it the way you are.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but now the form doesn't render at all.

Comment: If you copied my comment it is because I had a typo. `'user_register_form'` not registration form. If that doesn't work what kind of errors are you getting? You might have to mess with the access callback or maybe `'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because the form builder function [user_register_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_register_form/7) is expecting a couple of arguments, `$form_id` & `$form_date`, that you're not passing (see the [drupal_build_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7) docs to know more about what they're for).

If you want to provide a wrapper function around the user reg form, you can do something like this:

```
function my_module_customer_registration($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = user_register_form($form, $form_state);
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: It was indeed $form + $form_state I missed :) Thanks. I thought with drupal_get_form they were superfluous, but obviously I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you  add `user_register_form` in to hook menu

```
function my_module_menu() {
  $items['customer/register'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('user_register_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
 return $items;
}
```

Comment: This does work and is the solution I tried based on Sareed's comments. If I could approve two solutions I would, as this is works. The reason for using the attempted workaround with drupal_get_form was to do some additional form manipulation (showing/hiding fields) however and as Shawn pointed out, what I really missed was pasing the references to $form + $form_state